# Why Does Fluent-NHibernate Generate Inconsistent Column Names

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent Mapping for a project with this `ClassMap`:

```
    public class PricingMap : ClassMap<Pricing>
    {
            public PricingMap()
            {
                Init();
            }

            private void Init()
            {
                Table("distributership_pricing");

                ...

                References(x => x.Product);
                References(x => x.Distributor);
            }
 }
```

For the References, why does it generate `ProductId` for the Product relation, and `Distributor_Id` for the Distributor?

Comment: What do your Product and Distributor classes look like?

Comment: The ClassMaps for those?

Comment: The classmaps and class sources - there's almost definitely something in there that explains why FluentNH is generating idiosyncratic column names, if you're able to share them with us?

Comment: Grrr... I had a HasMany() on the Product ClassMap that referenced a seperate table with a KeyColumn specified as "ProductId".

Comment: @Dylan Create an answer with the text "Double check *all* your class maps." Then I will mark that as the answer lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't - I suspect there's a bug in one of your class maps; FluentNH will use the _Id suffix unless explicitly overridden by one of your class mappings or by a custom naming convention.